# create-react-app - inspect Redux store in production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am using `create-react-app` as an initial scaffold for an app that I am working on that exists within an existing php/jQuery app. After a bit of fiddling about I have been able to setup communication between the non-React app and the React app by using the method described [here](http://www.primaryobjects.com/2017/05/08/integrating-react-with-an-existing-jquery-web-application/).

What I'm currently doing is creating a `build` of the React app then inserting it into the non-React app, however I am finding troubleshooting the build version of the app slow and cumbersome because I am unable to inspect the Redux store through Chrome's Redux plugin. I am guessing that the ability to inspect the Redux store from a production ready build is disabled as part of `create-react-app`? I'm trying to avoid ejecting the app if possible so am wondering if there is any way to inspect the Redux store for the production build?

Comment: Are you able to use `Redux dev tools` at all?

Comment: No, not from within the production build. I just get `No store found. Make sure to follow the instructions.`

Answer (score 1):

There is another simple method to inspect redux store using 'React Dev Tools'. But I'm not sure whether it will work for your scenario as you are using React inside a Non-React app.

Simply open your dev tools and select your `Provider` component. Then you will see `== $r` sign right next to the component. What this basically says is you can you `$r` in the console to access the current instance of `Provider` component.

[image]

Now you can go to Console tab and enter the following line to see your current state.

`> . $r.store.getState()`

You can use this approach to inspect any other React component as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good to know! Will keep that in mind but I just realised where I had gone wrong. Will submit as answer to my own question... Thanks for your insight @Tharaka

Answer (score 1):

Just realised that it was completely my own fault - when setting up the configuration for Redux store I had specified:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const devToolsExtension = window.devToolsExtension;

  if (typeof devToolsExtension === 'function') {
    enhancers.push(devToolsExtension());
  }
}
```

I've removed the conditional on `process.end.NODE_ENV === 'development'` and I can now inspect Redux store from production build.

Thanks to commenters on suggestions. Sorry to waste your time!